# docker-compose down doesn't.. "down" the containers

Tags: docker-compose

I have a few systems where I use docker-compose and there is no problem.

However, I have one here where 'down' doesn't do anything at all.
'up' works perfectly though. This is on MacOS.

The project is nicknamed 'stormy', and here is the script:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    container_name: stormy_rabbitmq
    image: rabbitmq:management-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    expose:
      - 5672
    volumes:
      #- /appdata/stormy/rabbitmq/etc/:/etc/rabbitmq/
      - /appdata/stormy/rabbitmq/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
      - /appdata/stormy/rabbitmq/logs/:/var/log/rabbitmq/
    networks:
      - default

  settings:
    container_name: stormy_settings
    image: registry.gitlab.com/robinhoodcrypto/stormy/settings:latest 
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /appdata/stormy/settings:/appdata/stormy/settings
    external_links:
      - stormy_rabbitmq:rabbitmq
    networks:
      - default

  capture:
    container_name: stormy_capture
    image: registry.gitlab.com/robinhoodcrypto/stormy/capture:latest 
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /appdata/stormy/capture:/appdata/stormy/capture
    external_links:
      - stormy_rabbitmq:rabbitmq
    networks:
      - default

  livestream:
    container_name: stormy_livestream
    image: registry.gitlab.com/robinhoodcrypto/stormy/livestream:latest 
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /appdata/stormy/capture:/appdata/stormy/livestream
    external_links:
      - stormy_rabbitmq:rabbitmq
    networks:
      - default


networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: stormy-network
```

the 'up' script is as follows:

```
[ ! "$(docker network ls | grep stormy-network)" ] && docker network create stormy-network
echo '*****' | docker login registry.gitlab.com -u 'gitlab+deploy-token-******' --password-stdin
docker-compose down
docker-compose build --pull
docker-compose -p 'stormy' up -d
```

and the 'down' is simply:

```
docker-compose down
```

version:

> $ docker-compose -v
>
> docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b

when I do 'down', here is the output:

> $ docker-compose down
>
> Network stormy-network is external, skipping

and I put a verbose log output at: https://pastebin.com/Qnw5J88V

Why isn't 'down' working?

Comment: *docker ps* displays the container after *docker-compose down*?

Comment: yes, they are all running; not one goes down

Comment: Silly question, removing the *restart:* tag keeps the error?

Comment: just tried, no change. I have it in other scripts and this hasn't been a problem so far

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `docker-compose -p` option sets the [project name](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) which gets included in things like container names and labels; Compose uses it to know which containers belong to which Compose services.  You need to specify it on all of the commands that interact with containers (`docker-compose up`, `down`, `ps`, ...); if you're doing this frequently, setting the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable might be easier.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
export COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=stormy
docker-compose build --pull
docker-compose down
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: I was able to do a down with "docker-compose -p 'stormy' down"! thanks! when doing "docker-compose down --help", it doesn't show the -p option there :/

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this after I moved my docker-compose.yml while the container was running (oops).

Temporarily moving the .yml back and running `docker compose down` at that location succeeded. Perhaps `-p` would have helped had I used it on the very first `down`, but after that `docker compose ps` showed nothing and `down` didn't work for me.